# Facebook JavaScript helper with PHP SDK suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had this code and it was working without any issue. Suddenly this code stopped working. I followed several answers on Stack Overflow and even added a redirect URL in `getaccesstoken`. Then also I am getting an empty access token. I have updated the PHP SDK to the latest from GitHub.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    require_once( 'Facebook/autoload.php' );

    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'xxxxxx',
      'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
      'graph_api_version' => 'v7.0',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();

    try {

      // $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();    // This code is outdated in recent version. we need to give call back url

      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('https://xxxxxxx.com/redirect_url.php');
      echo '2222';
      echo $accessToken;

    }
    catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

      exit;
    }
    catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    if (! isset($accessToken)) {
      echo 'nope, no token.';
      exit;
    }
```

Here is the JavaScript part:

```
<script>
    logInWithFacebook = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                window.location.href = "https://xxxxxx.com/redirect_url.php";
            }
            else {
            }
        }, {scope: 'pages_show_list'});
        return false;
    };

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxxxxxx',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml : true,
            version: 'v7.0'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
        (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```

I get this output always:

> 222 nope, no token.

I want to get the accesstoken to perform some other task.

Comment: Can you show the JS part of this, too? Are you using the same API version in the initialization of that as well?

Comment: @04FS i tried all sorts of trial and error and facebook happily shows page list and i choose them and when i click last step OK then it should give accesstoken but its not giving

Comment: None of that is an answer to what I asked you. _“and when i click last step OK then it should give accesstoken”_ - did you reload your page? PHP of course can determine any such client-side changes only after a new request was made.

Comment: @04FS i have added javascript code.

Comment: I don’t see how adding the redirect URL makes sense here. That value is used when the server-side login flow is used, and the getAccessToken method of the JS helper does not even take it as a parameter. I would recommend that you debug into the PHP code a bit, to see where things start going wrong.

Comment: @04FS i dont get any error at all. i enabled error_reporting(E_ALL);
 but nothing comes. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by adding `status:true` to the `FB.Init()` options.